# Can I remap vim's `gf` command to follow Yii's path aliases?

Tags: php, vim, yii

I just learned of vim's `gf` command for navigating to files that are referenced in other files, such as c includes. I'm wanting to get this working within the Yii php framework, where files can be registered with the autoloader like this:

```
Yii::import('path.to.ClassName', true);
```

Using `gf` on `ClassName` has no effect because it's not the real file path. However, it would be easy enough to translate it to the file path, which is `path/to/ClassName.php`.

Furthermore, there are other mechanisms within Yii that utilize path aliases, such as begining a widget, which looks like this:

```
$this->beginWidget('ext.widgets.widgetName.ClassName');
```

Where `ext.widgets.widgetName.ClassName` is an alias to somewhere, perhaps `protected/extensions/widgets/widgetName/ClassName.php`. In this case the alias `ext` is expanded to its full path at runtime, so vim cannot know the full file path.

Is there a way to overload/remap `gf` so within a php project it could either:

1. calculate the correct file path, then go to the file, or if file not found then
2. perform a tag lookup of `ClassName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `:help includeexpr`.  The example listed there for Java might suit your purposes:

```
:set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\.','/','g')
```

More generally, see `:help gf` and then follow the jumps to the settings that control it (like I just did :).

Comment: Thanks David, this is helpful. But it does not solve the Yii-specific problem of file paths that use aliases, where simply replacing `.` with `/` will result in a file not found error. Do you know how to trap this error so I can then try a tag search?

Comment: Hmm, no I don't.  It seems like an unusual kind of tagging would be required.  At the very least you would need to make the runtime expansion mechanism available to vim, whereas both tagging and `gf` rely on static analysis.  Assuming you have Yii's source readily available, you could probably write a plugin or external tool for that purpose.

Comment: In my project, typing `<C-]>` will effectively find the class name under the cursor using ctags. So I was hoping to utilize ctags as a fallback when `gf` could not find the file.